# LinqToSql - Getting a list of distinct IDs from a nested list

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a property within a class, that I need to iterate through all the possible distinct IDs from a relationship.

I am within a User, which belongs to a Company. Companies, have many solutions and each solution has many "SolutionPortals". What I want, is a list of all distinct "PortalIds" from the "SolutionPortals" (SolutionPortal.PortalID) that are in the DB.

I can't for the life of me get this as a single list. I keep getting:

```
var solutionIds = from s in this.Company.Solutions.Select(s=>s.SolutionPortals)
                  select s.Select(sp=> sp.PortalID);
```

Of course this makes sense, since there is a list of Solutions, with a List of SolutionPortals, but I need to select JUST the IDS out into their own list.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> // <-- Don't want this
IEnumerable<int> // <-- I want this
```

Any help would be EXTREMELY appreciated.

Thanks/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) is the key here:

```
var solutionIds = this.Company
                      .Solutions
                      .SelectMany(s=>s.SolutionPortals)
                      .Select(sp => sp.PortalId)
                      .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need something like this:

```
var listOfIds = listOfSolutionPortals.SelectMany(sps => sps.Solutions)
                                     .Select(sp => sp.PortalId);
```

Comment: That put me on the right path. Thanks! I didn't know about the "SelectMany" extensions. Very handy.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
var solutionIds = (from s in this.Company.Solutions
                   .SelectMany(s => s.SolutionPortals)
                   select s.PortalID).Distinct();
```

Thanks Mehrdad!

Comment: I suggest not forcing yourself to use query expression syntax. I think this is more readable: `var solutionIds = this.Company.Solutions.SelectMany(s => s.SolutionPortals).Select(s => s.PortalID).Distinct();`